# Интегрировать свой сайт с сервисом идентификации

Tags: c#, saml

Добрый день.

Есть необходимость интегрировать свой сайт с сервисом идентификации esia.gosuslugi.ru.
По докам, которые удалось найти, он работает на Shibboleth и SAML2.

Подскажите, где можно посмотреть пример работы на C#. Возможно есть правильные готовые способы работы с этим сервисом.

Или посоветуйте, как с самой ЕСИА работать правильно надо.

Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите, если кто знает, хотя бы примерный алгоритм работы с IDP.

Comment: Хм. Мне гугл на аббревиатуру IDP ничего вообще внятного не выдаёт.

---
А есть официальная документация для хоть какого-то языка?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не точно выразился.

Я имел ввиду работу с IDP esia.gosuslugi.ru
Опыта работы с просто этими технологиями очень мало.

Документация есть:
http://minsvyaz.ru/common/upload/Metodicheskie_rekomendatsii_ESIA.pdf

Но так и хочется сказать словами из песни: "ну все понятно, но что конкретно..." :)

Comment: @Kononov_Andrey: Ага. Там что-то есть в приложении Г6. Пример на Java с неким OpenSAML.